# Ruby on Rails Heroku set first part of domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have developed a RoR app.  I would like to update it to handle more than one customer.  For instance, one customer might use ame.requestsys.com and another would be slc.requestsys.com.

Currently on Heroku, I have requestsys.com and www.requestsys.com

I was told that I need to have *.requestsys.com --> is that correct?
If yes, why won't Heroku let me add it?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to add wildcard domains on Heroku just like Agush stated: `$ heroku domains:add *.requestsys.com`

Comment: You might need to remove the exist entries to be able to add the wildcard.

Comment: Another reason why it might not be working is if you are have that domain in other app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line in the directory of your app do:

```
$ heroku domains:add *.requestsys.com
```

You can also do it from the heroku dashboard.

Then setup a CNAME in your DNS accordingly to point to yourapp.herokuapp.com

Try this guide for more info:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#wildcard-domains.

Basically what you wanna do is a multitenant app, there are a couple railscasts on the subject:

http://railscasts.com/episodes?search=multitenancy

But thats beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: The Railscasts on Multitenacy are well done, just a few weeks ago. They're absolutely worth their money.